# How can I access The TestCategory attribute in the TFS API or TFS Report?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, tfs, mstest

We have a rather complicated library of automated test.  We are using TestCategory and TestProperty help us keep things clean.  Now I want the ability to report on the categories after they run.

Does anyone know if the Test Category or Test Property in MSTest is accessible from the TFS Warehouse or better yet, through the TFS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TestCategory is not available in the tests results and thus isn't available via warehouse or API.  TestCategory can be used to filter the tests that are run during a build but that's it.  So you could create different test builds based on test category and then report based on each build.

You could alternatively associate automation to your test cases, then organize your test cases into suites and organize your reports based on suites.

[image]